# How can I reassure users about an unfamiliar domain name?

Tags: users, urls, security

I have a service, example-service.com.

I have customers customer-a.com, customer-b.com, etc.

We host a service for them on urls like customer-a.example-service.com

Users who are familiar with customer-a.com and trust it might be sent to customer-a.example-service.com and be worried that it is some sort of scam/fake site. (indeed, this is a common phishing method, making a domain like paypal.com.payment-service.com, users quickly see paypal.com in the url and trust it).

The users are sometimes sent there from a third party, not from customer-a.com.

We have a "What is Example Service?" thing in the footer with some explanation. How else could we reassure our users about the relationship between the two services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to have a link on customer-a.com site leading to your site. It would be even better if the users would sign in on customer-a.com and they used that authentication token on customer-a.example-service.com. Then the user would not have to worry about signing in to a different domain. You would use customer-a.com as an identity provider for your site - which would be more trusted by your users than having them sign in on example-service.com.

Comment: what we ended up doing is have the customer make a "partner page" on their site declaring their relationship with us, and then we link to that from the "What is Example Service?" page.

Answer (score 2):

Why not reverse this and host the sites on example-service.customer-a.com? Customer A can set up a subdomain on their domain and point it to your servers. It may not be practical in your situation, but at least worth considering.

Comment: Agree with this. Our current `download.example.com` site isn't hosted by us, but by our current Content Delivery Network partner. It also has a long `servername.datacenter.cdnprovider.com` name, but that's invisible to our customers.

Comment: yep, that's one solution, but not an option in this particular case.